# How to add link to all search below autocomplete popup in jQuery.ui.autocomplete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have search suggestion autocompletion using jQuery UI autocomplete plugin.
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

But how to add on the bottom of results popup item which behaves like on Quora(see below).

**Javascript**

```
$("#question_search").autocomplete({
  source:$('#question_search').data('source'),
  html: true,
  appendTo: "#search_results",
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    window.location=ui.item.value;
    return false;
  },
  focus: function( event, ui ) { },
  open: function( event, ui ) { });
```

**View**

```
<div id="question_search_form">
  <input type="text" id="question_search" data-source="<%= new_search_url %>" />
  <div id="search_results"></div>
</div>
```

**Example**

[image: Quora search autocomplete]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend overriding the `_renderMenu` then simply appending an anchor within a list-item.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( "#question_search" ).autocomplete({
    source:$('#question_search').data('source'),
    html: true,
    appendTo: "#search_results",
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        window.location=ui.item.value;
        return false;
    },
      focus: function( event, ui ) { },
      open: function( event, ui ) { }
}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderMenu = function( ul, items ) {
  $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderMenu.apply( this, [ul, items] );
  ul.append( '<li><a href="/search/'+ this.term + '">Search: '+ this.term + '</a></li>' );  
};
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/4pk3V/42/

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks, One more thing which I would like to achieve is instead of ``Some Button`` I would like to have ``<a href="/search/some_term">Search: some_term</a>`` But how to put that term here?

Comment: Thanks... that looks great in 1.9.1 as per the fiddle, but fails in 2.0.2 with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderMenu' of undefined"

Answer (score -2):

just make a div after the search results...?

Comment: not sure if adding a div after the search result will give the exact result required,
but overriding the _renderMenu and appending the  <a> tag within the list-item will work better as suggested above by @Dom