# Submit data from textbox OR Jquery autocomplete menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, form-submit, jquery-ui-autocomplete

EDIT: I found the answer from these two questions -
[How to add link to all search below autocomplete popup in jQuery.ui.autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466662/how-to-add-link-to-all-search-below-autocomplete-popup-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

[Send AJAX request by clicking a link without redirecting user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623019/send-ajax-request-by-clicking-a-link-without-redirecting-user)

I have a jquery autocomplete menu for book searches. The autocomplete is working fine, but I would still like the option of doing a search query (POST data) from the text typed in the text box, by pressing enter, and ignoring the autocomplete suggestions.

I've tried jquery form submit, which always disables the autocomplete menu. I'm not sure what to do.

Below is the code I have now with the autocomplete which is working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Your web-app is https, so your scripts need to be too -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">

    function post(path, params, method ='post') {

        // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
        // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
        const form = document.createElement('form');
        form.method = method;
        form.action = path;

        for (const key in params) {
            if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
                hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
                hiddenField.name = key;
                hiddenField.value = params[key];

                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
            }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
```

---

```
    $(document).ready(function() {



        $("#findBook").autocomplete({

            minLength: 0,
            scroll: true,

            source: function (request, response) {



                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + request.term,


                    success: function (data) {

                        var transformed = data.items.map(function (book) {
                            return {
                                title: book.volumeInfo.title,
                                author: book.volumeInfo.authors,
                                image: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
                            };
                        });


                        response(transformed.slice(0, 5));
                    }


                });


            },


            select: function(event, ui){

               //console.log(ui.title);


                event.preventDefault();

                var id = ui.item.title;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/book_profile_b/" + id,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: { id: id },
                    success: function(data){


                        post('/book_profile_b/'+id);


                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                        console.log(xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError)
                        alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);
                    }
                });



            },


        }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")

                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a><img class= 'imageClass' src='" + item.image + "' />" + item.title +  " " + "<div class=searchInfo>" +  "by" + " " + item.author + "</div>" + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul)
                .append('<li><a href="/book_profile/b/'+ this.term + '">Search: '+ this.term + '</a></li>' );



           };

        });
```

---

```
</script>





<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/home.css" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans|EB+Garamond|Encode+Sans+Expanded|Inconsolata|Karla|Manuale|Nunito+Sans|Pontano+Sans|Roboto+Slab:300|Rokkitt|Sanchez" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>






<div class="searchBook">


    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="findBook" />


</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel. Are you trying to do XMLHttpRequest POST request (AJAX POST request)?

Comment: A pure JavaScript solution?

Comment: Hi @Danny, Jquery would work too. I've actually moved on to trying to create a bar at the bottom that reads 'see all results for' + the text typed in the text box. When that box is clicked, it would post the data. A solution for a fixed item is in this answered question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878999/how-to-add-a-fixed-item-in-the-jquerys-autocomplete-list

Comment: I have a partial solution to add a link to the bottom, except it appends the link to every item, and I only want it appended once at the bottom. This is my code:

Comment: }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")

                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a><img class= 'imageClass' src='" + item.image + "' />" + item.title +  " " + "<div class=searchInfo>" +  "by" + " " + item.author + "</div>" + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul)
                    .append( '<li><a href="/search/'+ this.term + '">Search: '+ this.term + '</a></li>' );

Comment: Can you update your question with the proper version of the code that you finally have?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Hi, I updated the question with the edited code, the goal is to add a bar at the bottom of the list which has a link using the text typed in the box. Right now, the link is being added to each item in the list